# Texture showing errors (edges of texture)?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv

[image]

Here I have a simple white-to-transparent image in the UV editor.

[image]

I've selected a plane thats in correct proportion in size to the image, and I've unwrapped it.

[image]

[image]

At first, it looks just fine.

[image]

When you zoom in or focus at the very edge of the plane, you can see a little error: the texture and unwrap goes from white to transparent, but the object is showing a little white part at the edge of the object. It is small, but it is very noticeable in play-mode.

How can I fix this? How can I have the texture not show these errors?

Comment: Black on black is not really good to notice anything. Please post images with higher contrast. I can't see what you mean

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But the last image is the edge of the plane - I've just zoomed in. I'll get to it when I can.

Comment: How about preparing a sample with more contrast e.g. solid white?

Comment: Does it show up this way in the render too, or only in the viewport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cause

I think the texture gets blurred either because it is scaled out or scaled in via automatic mipmapping texture.

[image]

Blur means the adjacent texels are considered when calculating the color.

It will include any texel outside the UV area. It even wraps around the around the texture's border (which is the cause of the effect you discover).

[image]

## Solution

In both cases I suggest you shrink the UV-face that you get some border around the face (in UV-Editor).

[image]

## Reference

See [Avoid Seams in Textured Objects](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?235966-Avoid-Seams-in-Textured-Objects!&p=1982399&viewfull=1#post1982399)

Comment: This is a very recurring issue. Resizing tons of faces doesn't really seem to be an ideal solution. Is there a way to stop the "blur" rather than compensating for it?

Comment: You do not need to change tons of faces. Just to faces with the problem (corner to higher contrast colors and corner to texture border with higher contrast on the opposite side). And yes, when you know about that you can design your UV right from the beginning that way.

Comment: So, I'm trying out the solution. How exactly would this be done properly, so that the texture still covers *the same amount* of the UV image as before? In the above example the face is the entire image. If I have a larger image, the face will still cover the entire thing. Thus, I will shrink it down. But How much? In some specific areas I need to have the exact image/face scale so that it looks just like before.

Comment: I added images to the answer. I hope that makes it more clear. - To cover the same amount of texture ... increase the texture size and add a border to the image