# Render view showing random seams and causing blurring to textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, blur

I'm a bit new to blender, but I been working on this for about a week now and big hangup came once I got textures applied to the model.

It's hard to see, but there are visible seams in the rendered image down the center of the model, and mirrored seams in the shape of a '*V*' on the chest.
[image]
On top of that, the textures become more blurry as you zoom out. Obviously, neither of these problems are present in the unrendered view. (Before anyone asks, everything is set to *Blender Render*.)

The only advice I saw for blurring was making sure the mapping was set UV, which you can see from the picture that it is. The blurring and the seams may be unrelated but they are both hampering my progress severely, so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Update: For better reference-
[image]
I drew arrows pointing to the lines in which I'm referring to. I'm sorry they are faint but they become more noticeable as you zoom out. At first I thought they might have had to do with mirroring the model across the x axis, but the V shape under the circle in the chest disproves that theory, and there is also line around one of the edge loops for the knee.

My knowledge of the program is limited so if you need me to explain more I'll do the best I can.

Comment: I updated with new picture to help point things out. As for previewing... you can see I have two open viewports- One for the rendered appearance on the left and one with material shading for doing editing on the right.
I prefer the crisp textures of the right hand side.
As for the "seams" I know they're not blender seams but I can't think of any other word to describe them. They aren't part of the texture or the mesh.

Comment: [*Just educated myself on Ngons*](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/ngons-triangles-bad/) I'd like to think this is the problem since the chest is made up of Ngons, but the problem is the seams on the face and knees are surrounded by quads.

Also, I don't understand why triangles _would_ be bad as they stay flat no matter what- as opposed to the topography of non-flat quads and Ngons. Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I barely understand what I'm saying. Oh, and I recalculated the normals.

Comment: Generally yes, the amount of verts which form a face should not affect shading.. however that isn't always the case. Try enabling Antialiasing in the Render tab,that should minimize the problem. Also investigating a bit further, I think this is because of the bleeding (islands on the UV map almost exceed textured areas and background of the texture, in your case, white alpha, become to be visible). See [related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46685/1245). It looks like you've already done that but I think not enough. I baked new texture from yours with Margin 16 and saw no seams.

Comment: Baking did clear up the texture.
I don't know if I can get rid of this blur or not though.
Thanks for the help, regardless!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/black-lines-along-uv-mapped-model (probably even a duplicate).